# SQL dealing with 0 (zero) as denominator

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query in MS Access and the query does a division of two different counts from two tables. It looks like this:

```
Select Count(*)/(Select Count(*) FROM table1 where column1 = userInput) FROM table2;
```

When I run this, I'm asked to input a value for "userInput". However sometimes, the column (column1) will not have that value and it will return 0. Is there a way I can deal with this...For instance can I make the numerator turn 0 anytime the denominator is 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value to `NULL`:

```
Select (Count(*) /
        (Select iif(Count(*) = 0, NULL, COUNT(*)) from table1 where column1 = userInput
        )
       )
from table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Select 
    IIf(
        (Select Count(*) FROM table1 where column1 = userInput) = 0,
        0,
        Count(*)/(Select Count(*) FROM table1 where column1 = userInput))
From table2;
```